# Site works fine in Brave and Microsoft Edge (chromium based) but has problem in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, responsive-design

The site works totally fine, but the responsiveness has some problems in firefox. Instead of shrinks and adapt to the window size, some sections get hidden instead of show themselves.
HTML and CSS is the same, it's a very simple site, so I don't know why on FF I have these problems. [image: On Brave and Edge] [image: On Brave and Edge] [image: On Firefox] [image: On Firefox]

Code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Domine:wght@400;700&family=Lora:ital,wght@0,400;0,600;0,700;1,400;1,500&family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;700&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="icon" href="images/alebacce.ico">
<link href="mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 480px)" />
<link href="tablet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 960px)" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bacce's Angle</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
   
        <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>
        <div class="menu">
            <a href="./baccesangle.html">Home</a>
            <a href="#chisono">Chi sono</a>
            <a href="#skills">Skills</a>
            <a href="#interessi">Interessi</a>
            <a href="#chiamami"><span class="contactmenu">Contattami</span></a>
        </div>
      </nav>

  <div class="main">
    <picture>
   <source 
      media="(min-width: 650px)"
      srcset="images/webdevlr2.png">
   <source 
      media="(max-width: 465px)"
      srcset="images/webdevlr2mobile.png">
   <img src="images/webdevlr2.png" 
   alt="Welcome on my site!">
</picture>
    <div class="welcome">
      <p>
        <h1><strong>ALESSANDRO BACCELLI</h1></strong>
      </p>
      <p><em>Work in progress</em> WEB DEVELOPER</p>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="divide first">
  <div class="heading">
    <h1 id="chisono">Chi sono</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="section1">
    <div class="profile">
    <img src="images/profiledefmobile.png" alt="A picture of me">
    </div>
    <div class="biography">
      <p>Un ragazzo genovese di 24 anni, laureato in <em>Scienze della Comunicazione</em> da sempre appassionato di
        tecnologia e digitale. <br><br> Ho recentemente scoperto
        la mia passione per la programmazione grazie ai corsi di <strong><a
            href="https://www.start2impact.it/" target="blank">start2impact</a></strong>,
        iniziando il mio viaggio nel mondo di Html, CSS e via discorrendo... <br><br>
        Per quanto la strada sia ancora lunga ho fiducia nel futuro, questo sito vuole infatti essere l'inizio di un
        lungo percorso.</p>
         <div class="download">
    <button><a href="https://mega.nz/file/VNpETSiI#Z93X88NF5A-YwNvlLlN1qDqH9wesivKVRnLwK7WF9Hs" target="blank">Scarica il mio CV</a></button>
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>



  <div class="divide colordifferent">
  <div class="heading margin">
    <h1 id="skills">Skills</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="section2">
    <div class="hard">
      <h2>Hard skills</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Inglese fluente</li>
        <li class="modifiedli">HTML</li>
        <li class="modifiedli">CSS</li>
        <li>Canva</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="soft">
      <h2>Soft skills</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Autonomia</li>
        <li>Fast learner</li>
        <li>Empatia</li>
        <li>Ascolto attivo</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="divide">
  <div class="heading bottomodif">
    <h1 id="interessi">Interessi</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="section2">
    <div class="inte hard">
      <ul>
        <li id="programmazione">Coding</li>
        <li id="foto">Fotografia digitale</li>
        <li id="grafica">Grafica</li>
        <li id="discover">Scoprire nuove cose</li>
        <li id="cucina">Cucina</li>
        <li id="videogiochi">Video-games</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="ressi soft">
      <ul>
        <li id="self">Self-growth</li>
        <li id="mind">Mindfulness</li>
        <li id="fit">Fitntess &amp; Health</li>
        <li id="storia"><span class="history">Storia e Antropologia</span></li>
        <li id="book">Lettura</li>
        <li id="eco">Ambiente</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <footer id="chiamami">
    <div class="foot"></div>
    <div class="foot contact"><a href="mailto:ale.baccelli@libero.it" target="_blank">E-mail</a><span class="not"><br></span><span class="bracket"> &nbsp; |&nbsp; </span><a
        href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/alessandro-baccelli1996/" target="_blank">Linkedin</a><span class="not"><br></span><span class="bracket"> &nbsp;|&nbsp; </span><a
        href="https://talent.start2impact.it/home/student_index" target="_blank">Start2impact</a><br>
      <br> ALESSANDRO BACCELLI 2020 &#169;</div>
    <div class="foot"></div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #E5DDC8;
    color: #1F1F1F;
}

/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #EBFDFF;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #B1C5E7;
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #7699D4;
}

h1,
h2 {
    font-family: "Montserrat", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
    color: #141414;
}

nav {

    text-align: right;
    font-size: 120%;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    z-index: 99999;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #004369;
}

.menu {
    margin: 0 30px 0 0;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #004369;
}

.menu a {
    clear: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 10px;
    line-height: 100px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.menu a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.contactmenu {
    color: #7EDD9A;
    z-index: 10;
}

label {
    margin: 0 40px 0 0;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 100px;
    display: none;
    width: 26px;
    float: right;
    z-index: 10;
    color: white;
}

#toggle {
    display: none;

}


@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    label {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 10;
    }

    .menu {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
        z-index: 9999;

    }

    .menu a {
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEB;
        margin: 0;
        z-index: 10;

    }

    .menu a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
    }


    #toggle:checked+.menu {
        display: block;
    }


}




.main {
    display: block;
    z-index: -1;
    position: relative;
}

.welcome {
    display: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 3em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #1F1F1F;
}

.welcome h1 {
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.main img {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.divide {
    height: 900px;
    margin-top: 120px;
}

.heading {
    font-family: "Montserrat",
        "Helvetica",
        "Arial",
        sans-serif;
    color: #141414;
    font-size: 200%;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.first {
    height: fit-content;
}

.section1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 958px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.profile {
    text-align: center;
}


.biography {
    align-self: center;
    font-size: 140%;
    margin-left: 80px;
}

.biography a {
    color: #01949A;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.biography a:hover {
    color: #004369;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.download {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.biography button {
    font-size: 130%;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #01949A;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: none;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.biography button a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.biography button a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #004369;
}

.biography button:hover {
    background-color: #004369;
}

.section2 {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    font-size: 200%;

}

.colordifferent {
    background-color: #E5F9E0;
    padding-top: 120px;
}

.margin {
    margin-bottom: 145px;
}

.hard h2,
.soft h2 {
    margin-bottom: 25px;

}

.section2 ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 140px;
}

.section2 li {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    ;
}

.section2 ul li::before {
    content: "\2705";
    margin-right: 25px;
}

.section2 ul .modifiedli::before {
    content: "";
}

.section2 ul #programmazione::before {
    content: "‍";
}

.section2 ul #foto::before {
    content: "";
}

.section2 ul #grafica::before {
    content: "";
}

.section2 ul #discover::before {
    content: "️";
}

.section2 ul #cucina::before {
    content: "‍";
}

.section2 ul #videogiochi::before {
    content: "";
}

.section2 ul #self::before {
    content: "";
}

.section2 ul #mind::before {
    content: "‍♂️";
}

.section2 ul #fit::before {
    content: "";
}

.section2 ul #storia::before {
    content: "";
}

.section2 ul #book::before {
    content: "";
}

.section2 ul #eco::before {
    content: "♻️";
}

.bottomodif {
    margin-bottom: 110px;
}

footer {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: #004369;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 130%;
}

.foot {
    width: 33.33333%;
}

footer a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

footer a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.not {
    display: none;
}
```

CSS Tablet

```
body {
    width: 100%;
}

.divide,
.section1 {
    width: 100%;
}

.first {
    height: fit-content;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.section1 {
    width: 90%;
    display: block;
}

.profile {
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.profile img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.biography {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
}

.biography button {
    margin-top: 70px;
}

.bracket {
    display: none;
}

.not {
    display: unset;
}
```

CSS Mobile

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-size: 90%;
    width: 100%;
}


.main {
    display: block;
}

.main img {
    display: block;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    position: static;

}

.welcome {
    display: none;
}

.divide {
    height: fit-content;
    width: 100%;
}



.section1,
.section2 {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: initial;
    overflow-y: auto;

}

.profile img {

    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.biography {
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.hard,
.soft {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.hard h2,
.soft h2 {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.hard ul,
.soft ul {
    text-align: left;
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
    word-wrap: break-word;

}

.hard ul li,
.soft ul li {
    padding-left: 65px;
    text-indent: -65px;
}

.inte,
.ressi {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.ressi ul {
    margin-bottom: 150px;

}

.history {
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.bracket {
    display: none;
}

.not {
    display: unset;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to provide some code and a more specific explanation of your issues, or ideally a minimal test case. There's not enough information here to help you.

Comment: @velvetkevorkian thanks for your feedback, I've updated everything. I'm sorry, I thought it was something common and easily fixable